# how to get document() to accept µ

Tags: r, devtools

I have been using this code

```
nutList <- gsub("_µg","",nutList, fixed = TRUE)
```

to remove the string "_µg" from the variable nutList for at least a year and have had no problems. Now I'm trying use document() to see where I have problems in getting ready for a package.

```
Error in parse(text = lines, n = -1, srcfile = srcfile) : [filename] : unexpected INCOMPLETE_STRING
nutList <- gsub("_
```

It appears that document() doesn't like the µ that is there. How can I modify the code so it is accepted?

Comment: Hi JerryN, can you provide us with all or part of `nutList` so we can cut & paste into our R sessions to reproduce the problem? Thanks :)

Comment: Have you put `Encoding: UTF-8` in the Description file?

Comment: I had not. Now I have and the problem is gone.